# Quick Objective-C Question

Tags: objective-c

Consider this line of code, data is a method parameter:

```
myVar = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
```

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here, but I think that it's assigning myVar to the data contained in data, incrementing it's reference count. Could someone confirm or deny this? Thanks!

Source of original code snippet- see listing 1: [Apple Dev Article](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ NSMutableData data ] will return an auto-released object (convenience method).

So it will be automatically released when the auto-release pool of the current run-loop is drained.

You are retaining it to prevent this...

Then you are sure you have a valid pointer to the object.
That's correct, simply don't forget to release it when you don't need it anymore...

**EDIT**

For instance:

```
[ [ [ [ [ [ NSData data ] retain ] release ] autorelease ] retain ];
```

Retain count is 2, as auto-releasing an object does not change the retain count...
But the object has been placed twice in the current auto-release pool, so it will be released twice on the next drain...

Comment: Thanks, one remaining question: what is the significance of the word data after NSMutableData?

Comment: It's the name of the class method: + ( NSData )data. Also known as static methods in other langauges.

Comment: @Macmade: actually, class methods in Objective-C *aren't* analogous to static methods.

Comment: @jiehr They are depending on the language you're talking about. (Java, for instance...) ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I was looking for the data method declaration in the NSMutableData declaration, I didn't think to look up the inheritance hierarchy.

@Sherm Thanks for your concern, but I wasn't actually trying to accomplish the task in the article. I just didn't understand the syntax. Objective-C is syntactically different from anything I've ever worked in, so it's taking some getting used to.

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing your myVar variable with a new instance of NSMutableData using a convenience method, and then retaining it.

It's basically the same as `myVar = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];` since you are retaining it anyway.

Comment: Careful, variable initialisation and variable assignment are two different things in C (and by extension, in Objective-C).

Comment: Fair enough, so the correct way of saying this is that the code above is assigning a new instance of NSMutableData to myVar?

Comment: Yep, that's the more "by the book" way to say it. I don't think it's likely to confuse anyone though, I'm just a bit of a pedant.

Answer (score 1):

In the above, "data" is a class method that returns a new object of class NSMutableData. Since "data" is not one of the methods that imply ownership of the object it returns, the object's "retain" method is called to establish ownership. The caller is now responsible for relinquishing its ownership claim when it's finished with the object.